# Complex integral and contour

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I'm trying to compute the integral $\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{dx}{2+x^n}$

So my attempt is finding the roots of $2+x^n$ that are $e^{\pi i}$$e^{\frac{2  \pi m}n} $ for $m=1,2...,n-1$ and then define the contour of the integral.

After that apply Residue Theorem.

Please tell me if I'm doing this right.

Comment: That's the right approach.  How far have you gotten?

Comment: I'm not sure if those are the roots of the denominator, but the contour is like a piece of cake with angle $\frac{2 \pi}{n} $

Comment: Here's your answer... just to check your final solution:  $\frac{\pi  2^{\frac{1}{n}-1} \csc \left(\frac{\pi }{n}\right)}{n}$

Comment: I don't know how you obtain $csc(\frac{\pi}{n})$

Comment: First:  simplify your $e^{i \pi}$ using Euler's famous equation.

Comment: Are the roots of the form $2^{1/n}$$e^{\frac{i2k \pi + \pi}{n}}$

Comment: You still have a typo in the formula in your last comment (and there are $n$ roots, not $n - 1$). Since you know what contour to take, determine which of the roots lie inside the contour. Then parametrize the ray $\arg x = 2 \pi/n$ and write out the integral along the ray.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution (so please don't downvote).

Here are your poles:

[image]

Comment: Surely that's not what a regular polygon with $n$ vertices looks like. (What you have is apparently $(-2)^{1/n}$ for successive values of $n$.)